# Initializer element is not constant - C

Tags: c, constants

I'm getting two errors :
Initializer element is not constant in the  2nd last line below in the code
Expected declaration specifiers '...' before string constant    in the last line

```
#define K 10.0
typedef double (*TFunc)(double);
double alpha,x;

double f(double x)
{
   return x*x;
}

double derive(TFunc f, const double x0)
{
    const double dx = 1.0e-6; // or similar
    double dy = f(x0+dx)-f(x0-dx);
    return dy/(2.*dx);   
}
double fp = derive(f, K);
printf("%lf\n",fp);
```

Comment: You can't be using exactly that code (or can never expect the code shown to work) — it won't compile, but the `double fp = derive(f, K);` line would give the error you claim.  And the `printf()` must be called within a function.  Within a function, the definition of `fp` would be fine, as would the call to `printf()`.  So, either your code fragment is incomplete or you're misunderstanding how a program works and you need to provide a `main()` function — or some other function — which defines `K`  and contains the last two lines of your fragment.

Comment: Where do f and K values come from ?

Comment: @MartinVerjans: `f` is the function defined starting in the third line of code.  `K` is undefined.

Comment: Your K is not constant, where is it defined ?

Comment: @MartinVerjans f is defined (the first function) but no clue about K

Comment: f is the function as defined and sorry about K it is defined as #define K 10.0 in the beginning of the code

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thx yes I figured it for f 5 seconds before your answer. Didn't even notice the printf and fp declaration weren't in a function...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : Yes I rectified the mistakes : Put the last two lines inside a main function and I'm getting this error still : In function `main':
grds.c:(.text+0xc9): undefined reference to `grprintf'

Comment: Where do you think the `grprintf()` function is defined?  It's a different error from what you were getting previously, though.  The previous ones were from the compilation phase; the current one is from the linking phase (traditionally performed by the `ld` program invoked by the C compiler on your behalf).  Either you forgot to link the file containing `grprintf()` or you accidentally added `gr` in front of `printf()` and need to remove those two letters.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : I hadn't defined any, I just deleted a few redundant header files and it compiles nicely now! Thanks a tonne guys! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add any block of code you want to run first during the execution in to a `main` function. In your case, you should put the code:

```
double fp = derive(f, K);
printf("%lf\n",fp);
```

into a `main` function

```
int main() {
  double fp = derive(f, K);
  printf("%lf\n",fp);
}
```

Make sure you include the `stdio.h` library at the beginning of file since you are using `printf` function. Also, make sure you define constant `K` somewhere. I updated your code according to my suggestion above and it compiled without errors or warnings:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef double (*TFunc)(double);
double alpha,x;
double f(double x)
{
  return x*x;
}
double derive(TFunc f, const double x0)
{
  const double dx = 1.0e-6; // or similar
  double dy = f(x0+dx)-f(x0-dx);
  return dy/(2.*dx);   
}

int main() {
  const double K = 1.0;
  double fp = derive(f, K);
  printf("%lf\n",fp);
}
```

Comment: The line `double alpha,x;` should probably be removed alltogether. It's not needed at all

Comment: @VietHTran : Thanks for the suggestions, such silly mistakes I did! I tried compiling your code and I'm getting this error : 
In function `main':
grds.c:(.text+0xc9): undefined reference to `grprintf'

Comment: What is `grprintf`? This is not a standard function.

Comment: @Jabberwocky : Ya I know, weird. This is the exact error I'm getting :-
/tmp/cc7Jj1Np.o: In function `main':
grds.c:(.text+0xd3): undefined reference to `grprintf'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @Jabberwocky I think OP is working on the code at the moment. He will probably use it later on so I decided to keep it there.

Comment: @Jabberwocky@VietHTran : Thanks guys it's working now! I just deleted a few header files and it works like a charm!

Comment: No problem! Glad I can help :)